# How to properly override babel@7 plugins for separate webpack server/client configurations

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm using a single `.babelrc` config and using it in `webpack.config.client.js` and `webpack.config.server.js` with babel-loader.

**.babelrc:**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "debug": false,
        "modules": false,
        "loose": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/react"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

The problem is, react-hot-loader find it's way into compiled server code.
I did some research and I see that babel 7 allows to [configure overrides](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#overrides) for such case.

I tried to implement it, but the "env" part never gets overridden:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "debug": false,
        "modules": false,
        "loose": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/react"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "overrides": {
    "include": "./src/server/index.js", // ?
    "env": {
      "development": {
        "plugins": [] 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: Are you setting the environment somewhere? If so, how.

Comment: I set env with dotenv in webpack and server. The env is working. In development, react-hot-loader plugin is in client bundle and server bundle. I'm looking how to remove it from server bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Babel doesn't know anything about your client/server differentiation. Your `"include": "./src/server/index.js",` check would affect that single file, but not your conceptual server bundle.

Realistically, there are a bunch of ways to do this, but I'll just list a couple to start.

One would be to use `env` and have 4 instead of 2 (`production-client`, `production-server`, `development-client`, `development-server`). Then you could do

```
"env": {
  "development-client": {
    "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
  },
}
```

Alternatively, you could set another environment variable, e.g.

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=development BUNDLE_NAME=server webpack --config webpack.config.server.js
```

and rename your config to be a `.babelrc.js` file, and do

```
module.exports = {
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "debug": false,
        "modules": false,
        "loose": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/react"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": 
        process.env.BUNDLE_NAME === "server" 
          ? [] 
          : ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
    },
    "production": {}
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution will have to do for now. It would be nice not to introduce 2/4 env variables though, because I build client and server together with a single variable - NODE_ENV.  Once I figure out how to use overrides I will update here.

Comment: What do you mean with a single variable? If you expand the question to elaborate on why my proposals are less than ideal for your case, I can expand my answer with more alternatives. There is an approach that would use `overrides`, but it makes things more complicated in your Webpack config, so I was avoiding it.

Comment: Well, my webpack setup is weird and I don't feel like changing it, so I look for lazy solutions. I use 1 babel config for client and server and overrides sounded straight forward, without messing with env or adjust npm tasks. I eventually converted to .babelrc.js and introduced CLIENT=true variable like you said. Not meant to say it's not ideal solution. Thanks for your time